# set.connect only works on first button

Tags: android, set, android-constraintlayout, connect

Im trying to make a Scrollable area with a dynamic number of Buttons, but I cant seem to programmaticly add more than one

For some Reason, the following code only works on the button with id 100, and not with any following ones, does anyone know why? 
I have tried using a loop to add the buttons, but the same problem arises

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet;

public class MainActivity  extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.li);
        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
        set.clone(layout);

        //Button 1:
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Hello");
        button.setId(100);
        set.connect(button.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 32);
        set.connect(button.getId(),ConstraintSet.RIGHT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);
        set.connect(button.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);
        set.constrainHeight(button.getId(), 200);
        set.applyTo(layout);
        layout.addView(button);

        //Button 2:
        Button newbutton = new Button(this);
        newbutton.setText("aaa");
        newbutton.setId(101);
        set.connect(newbutton.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 32);
        set.connect(newbutton.getId(),ConstraintSet.RIGHT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);
        set.connect(newbutton.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);
        set.constrainHeight(newbutton.getId(), 200);
        set.applyTo(layout);
        layout.addView(newbutton);


    }
}
```

EDIT: My Xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="52dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="52dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="181dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="4dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/li"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:minHeight="732dp"></androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What is your xml?

Comment: Im sorry, made an edit

Comment: You have just one button in your xml, how do you want to get several buttons?

Comment: im adding 2 More in the Java code, the one button in xml is in the middle and does nothing

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!!! All I did was move the layout.addView(newbutton); further up

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet;

public class MainActivity  extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.li);
        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
        set.clone(layout);

        //Button 1:
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Hello");
        button.setId(100);
        set.connect(button.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 32);
        set.connect(button.getId(),ConstraintSet.RIGHT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);
        set.connect(button.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);
        set.constrainHeight(button.getId(), 200);
        set.applyTo(layout);
        layout.addView(button);

        //Button 2:
        Button newbutton = new Button(this);
        newbutton.setText("aaa");
        newbutton.setId(1375);
        layout.addView(newbutton);
        set.connect(newbutton.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 300);
        set.connect(newbutton.getId(),ConstraintSet.RIGHT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);
        set.connect(newbutton.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);
        set.constrainHeight(newbutton.getId(), 200);
        set.applyTo(layout);



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add your buttons to the XML file and use `findViewById(R.id.button);` to every button